# elastic watcher does not attach documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-x-pack, packetbeat, elastic-cloud

I am using cloud elastic service and I have watcher entry that will alert me every hour about the count of packetbeat count. The code can be seen here...

https://ghostbin.com/paste/m5jqr

This is working as expected. But the attachment is just the count of documents and not the actual documents. I tried to send visualization or reports as explained here...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/actions-email.html

But I keep getting an error that says the report is not found.
How do I attach a document to email alert?

Comment: You have "size": 0 in your query body. Which, by definition, will not return the documents that matched. If you want them, bump that size up.

Comment: Correct. Can you add this comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "size": 0 in your query body. Which, by definition, will not return the documents that matched. If you want them, bump that size up.